# How to include a file in Test Bundle swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have json file that I want to include in the test bundle so I can just read this json for my tests.

So I created a file called "test.json", it is in my Tests folder.

Now I want to read this file. I am reading it like this, the code here is in the test file in test bundle:

```
 let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
 var url = bundle.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")
```

the url is nil every single time. I swear that file is there, if I open it in finder, it's under the same directory as the test-info.plist. I even tried the main bundle but it is still nil!!

Where is this file????

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: YourTestClass.self)
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json")
let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
```

Comment: This is the exact correct answer, and should be selected as the answer.

Comment: Make sure you select "Copy Files If Needed, "Create Groups", and specify your test target if you're using the JSON for unit testing.

Comment: If you need the url of a resource, you can use:
```swift
guard let fileUrl = Bundle(for: YourTestClass.self).url(forResource: "jsonFile", withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("jsonFile.json not found.")
        }
```